# file_get_contents parse json insert database

Tags: json, laravel, parsing

Hi I encountered a problem. I will record the data I received from the database.

```
JSON=>
{
    "success": true,
    "timestamp": 1565251506,
    "base": "EUR",
    "date": "2019-08-08",
    "rates": {
        "AED": 4.119657,
        "AFN": 87.689574,
        "ALL": 121.192477,
        "AMD": 533.113395,
        "ANG": 1.998509,
        "AOA": 398.760307,
        "ARS": 51.036305,
        "AUD": 1.654423
    }
}
```

After Json decode

```
array:5 [
  "success" => true
  "timestamp" => 1565205306
  "base" => "EUR"
  "date" => "2019-08-07"
  "rates" => array:168 [
    "AED" => 4.118588
    "AFN" => 87.74397
    "ALL" => 121.002609
    "AMD" => 534.279745
    "ANG" => 2.001014
   ]
]
```

I want this=> But How do I get quote and rate?

```
$response = file_get_contents("rate.json");
    $datas = json_decode($response, true);
     foreach ($datas as $data) {
        $rates = new Rate();
        $rates->base = $datas['base'];
        $rates->quote = 'AED';
        $rates->rate = '4.119657';
        $rates->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping over the wrong thing here, you should be looping over the rates and saving the corresponding key and value:

```php
$response = file_get_contents("rate.json");
$data = json_decode($response, true);
foreach ($data['rates'] as $quote => $rate) {
    $rates = new Rate();
    $rates->base = $data['base'];
    $rates->quote = $quote;
    $rates->rate = $rate;
    $rates->save();
}
```